# Take a list with numpy functions and insert in loop

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

i need some help iterating through a loop of numpy functions. First I started to calculate all the values i was looking for and stored them in a dictionary.

```
  calculations[keys[0]] = [np.mean(matrix, axis=0),np.mean(matrix, axis=1),np.mean(list)]
  calculations[keys[1]] = [np.var(matrix, axis=0),np.var(matrix, axis=1),np.var(list)]
  calculations[keys[2]] = [np.std(matrix, axis=0),np.std(matrix, axis=1),np.std(list)]
  calculations[keys[3]] = [np.max(matrix, axis=0),np.max(matrix, axis=1),np.min(list)]
  calculations[keys[4]] = [np.min(matrix, axis=0),np.min(matrix, axis=1),np.max(list)]
  calculations[keys[5]] = [np.sum(matrix, axis=0),np.sum(matrix, axis=1),np.sum(list)]
```

Then I thought is there a better war to do this, via a loop. I tried some f string things, but it didn't work out.

```
list = [i for i in range(9)]

matrix = np.reshape(list,(3,3))

keys = ['mean','variance','standard deviation', 'max','min','sum']
operator = ['np.mean','np.var','np.std','np.max','np.min','np.sum']

calculations = {}

for i in range[len(keys)]:
    
    calculations[keys[i]] = [f'{operater[0]}'(matrix, axis=0),f'{operater[0]}'(matrix, axis=1),f'{operater[0]}'(list)]
```

is there a way to go?

thanks in advance

Comment: do you have an example of the output that you are seeking pls ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`list` is a keyword and therefore should not be used as a variable, furthermore you need to use round `()` brackets for `range`, not square `[]` ones.
In Python, functions are first class members, so you can just pass them around and save them in a list. Just do this:

```
import numpy as np

numbers = list(range(9))

matrix = np.reshape(numbers,(3,3))

keys = ['mean','variance','standard deviation', 'max','min','sum']
operator = [np.mean, np.var, np.std, np.max, np.min, np.sum]

calculations = {}
for i in range(len(keys)):
    calculations[keys[i]] = [operator[i](matrix, axis=0),operator[i](matrix, axis=1),operator[i](numbers)]
```

Comment: thx for your quick feedback. works perfect!